# How can I handle an alt graph keystroke?

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to add a keyboard binding to a JTextField, but I cannot make it work using the alt graph key.

I followed the [keyboard bindings tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html) and tried this:

```
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("altGraph ENTER"), ...
inputMap.put(getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK), ...
```

but the action is never triggered. If I replace **altGraph** with **alt** it works.

**What can I do to make it work?**

If it matters: I'm using Java 6 and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK)
```

?

Comment: Yes, I did. In my tests I later tried with the letter "O" to make sure, altgr+enter is not a special case.